# I cannot see Japanese or Korean text

Tags: windows-7, language

I am using Windows 7 and I have installed the language packs, but I still cannot see them. Even under choose a display language, there is English, and then two words made out of squares (Korean & Japanese).

I am not sure what the do, I deleted FNTCACHE.DAT like someone with the same problem said to do, but not even that worked.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The font you are using does not support Japanese or Korean glyphs. Use a different font such as:

- DejaVu
- Segoe UI

There is also [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) of fonts on wikipedia.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I am using the default font. I went into Windows Color and Appearance and it said I was using Segoe UI.

Am I changing the font the wrong way?

Comment: It was just a suggestion. When I can't see text in Russian or Chinese for example, it's almost always because of the font. You wrote "I have installed the language packs, but I still cannot see them." What can you not see? The language packs or Korean menus and text? Add a screenshot.

Comment: I have already installed both Japanese and Korean font packs, but they do not work. For example, I am not trying to change my display language I just want to be able to see the text.
http://i.imgur.com/F94XJcD.png
I cannot see Korean or Japanese  even though I have already installed the language packs.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but does anyone else have any tips? I haven't been able to find out anything and I need to see these languages. Thanks!